# Dot symbol in docker compose environment variables doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with environment variables set like:

```
 identity-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
      - SpaClient=http://${ESHOP_EXTERNAL_DNS.NAME_OR_IP}:5104
```

It's just an example from https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/docker-compose.override.yml.

The issue: I replaced underscore symbol with dot symbol here: `ESHOP_EXTERNAL_DNS_NAME_OR_IP` -> `ESHOP_EXTERNAL_DNS.NAME_OR_IP`.
After that, If I try to build docker-compose project in VS, it will not work. The error looks like:

```
Error   DT1001  Invalid interpolation format for "environment" option in service "identity-api":"SpaClient=http://${ESHOP_EXTERNAL_DNS.NAME_OR_IP}:5104"    
docker-compose  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets 202
```

So the question: what is wrong with the variable name here? Is dot symbol supported or not? Or maybe it can be escaped somehow?

Answer (score 0):

In general, environment variable names with dots in them are allowed at a technical level but aren't well supported in any context, and I'd choose a different name.

In Docker Compose, it looks like [the regexps used to identify variable expansions](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/compose/config/interpolation.py#L97-L98) only support ASCII letters, digits, and underscores.  This suggests dots in environment variable names aren't supported, and there's no way to escape them.

I think variables with dots in them also aren't supported in shell scripts, but I'm having trouble proving that to myself reading the POSIX spec.  A [Name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_235) also only consists of ASCII letters, digits, and underscores; [parameters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05) either have a name, a number, or a single symbol; and variables are parameters with names; but none of the formal description of this says a "name" is a Name.

One easy thing to demonstrate is running the `bash` shell in the `ubuntu` Docker image.  We can use the `docker run -e` option to set arbitrary environment variables (that don't contain `=`) but we can't really use any shell features to expand variables with dots:

```
host$ docker run --rm -it -e foo=A -e foo.bar=B ubuntu
# Demonstrate the environment variable is set:
root@227bec28c674:/# env | grep foo
foo.bar=B
foo=A
# It won't get expanded without braces:
root@227bec28c674:/# echo $foo.bar
A.bar
# With braces, it's considered illegal syntax:
root@227bec28c674:/# echo ${foo.bar}
bash: ${foo.bar}: bad substitution
```